# How to call $.extend object from itself recursively?

Tags: jquery, recursion, extends

Basically, am trying to write an extension on jQuery that generates a random number, but will want the ability to not add numbers it already generated, and those from a list, so it doesn't add them again, so decided to use `$.extend` for this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.extend({
        randomNumber: function (checks) {
            var checks = checks || [];
            // Generate random number and store it in rand variable.

            if (checks.length > 0) {
                if ($.inArray(rand, checks) !== -1) {
                    this.randomNumber(checks); // This bit does not work, how to call this function again?
                }
            }
            return rand;
        }
    });
```

So `this.randomNumber` is not a function, and I'm not sure how to call this same function to be recursive here.  Any help please?

Comment: You can do this without recursion. Just generate a new random number until you find an used one.

Comment: Thanks Yeldar for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question you actually asked is to give the function a name:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.extend({
        randomNumber: function randomNumber(checks) {
        // Here ---------------^
            var checks = checks || [];
            // Generate random number and store it in rand variable.

            if (checks.length > 0)
            {
                if($.inArray(rand, checks) !== -1) {
                     randomNumber(checks);  // <=== No `this`
                }
            }
            return rand;
       }
});
```

That's called a *named function expression* (NFE), which is a function expression (rather than declaration) that gives the function a name. The name is in-scope within the function, but not outside it. Several years back, both Safari and IE had...isues...with NFEs, but Safari's was resolved many, many versions back. IE8 still has [the IE problem with NFEs](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html), but it wouldn't impact the above, and it's fixed in IE9+.

---

Unrelated, but you probably need to use the return value from the recursive call, as well. And there's no need for creating the `checks` array if it's not given to you:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.extend({
        randomNumber: function randomNumber(checks) {
            var rand = /* Generate random number */;

            if (checks && $.inArray(rand, checks) !== -1) {
                 rand = randomNumber(checks);
            }
            return rand;
       }
});
```

...and as [Yeldar pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775548/how-to-call-extend-object-from-itself-recursively#comment55317846_33775548), you don't need recursion for this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.extend({
        randomNumber: function(checks) {
            var rand;

            do {
                rand = /* Generate random number */;
            } while (checks && $.inArray(rand, checks) !== -1);

            return rand;
       }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that last one without recursion helped me.  The other ways to do this did not work for me, as it would call the function no more than 3 times, and rand would return undefined, which was odd.  But using last function seems perfect now.

Comment: @SolomonClosson: The second one would call the function as often as needed to avoid duplication, not just three times; and he `undefined` thing would be if you didn't assign to `rand` (as the second one above does). But yes, if you don't need recursion, the last is simplest.

Comment: The `checks` array will most likely be an extremely long array, something like 1000+.  Just hoping that it doesn't take forever to generate.  Thanks again!

Comment: @SolomonClosson: Probably not. But if it's going to be that long, you're definitely better off without recursion, as most JavaScript engines don't have tail call optimization yet (they will, it's required by the latest spec), so those stacks would get *deep*.

Answer (score 1):

very easily [use this](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.extend({
        randomNumber: function randomNumber(checks) { // named function
            var checks = checks || [];
            // Generate random number and store it in rand variable.

            if (checks.length > 0)
            {
                if($.inArray(rand, checks) !== -1) {
                     /*return*/ randomNumber(checks); // named function is available here, maybe return the value??
                }
            }
            return rand;
       }
});
```

as [@Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33775642/3591273) mentions maybe a return is needed as well (added in comments)